# Execute a method if stream has the right value in it | Flutter | RxDart

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, flutter-streambuilder

Let us say that I have a stream (A) that could either get : SuccessModel or the FailureModel.

- I subscribe to this stream A using a StreamBuilder and well, I just want to route to the next page if this stream contains SuccessModel and stay at the same page if it contains the FailureModel.
- Now, since this is a StreamBuilder it always expects me to return a Widget but in this case I might want to just use Navigator to route to the next page.

Considering the above scenario, how should I go about it?

Should I just return an empty container and probably Future.delayed into the next page (upon success) or is there a method that I could use on my stream A so that I define a function or listener inside of my bloc class and it executes the right set of functions (routes) based upon the value that stream gets..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: in that case you should not use `StreamBuilfer` at all - instead use `Stream.listen` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `stream` and you want your UI to redirect to the right `Route`, depending on `stream`'s value.

If you're using a `Router 1.0`, just `listen` to `stream` inside your widget and there decide whether to `push` a route or not.

Or, if you're using a `Router 2.0`, and maybe with `GoRouter` you can listen to that stream directly in your `ChangeNotifier` class, so that you redirect your user based on `stream`'s value.